# Design is empty for the layout in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecu2p.png)

It showed:

Rendering problems: The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate: 
 - PorterDuff Color Filters are not supported. (Ignore for this session) 
Ignore all fidelity warnings for this session

The component tree and properties also empty.

Does anybody know what's the problem here? Thanks a lot, in advance.

Comment: Try to rebuild, your project.

Comment: I've tried that and it's still empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed Android version into a higher level and the problem has been solved.